# How to get the data in a text field based on the value in a dropdown box which are populated from database?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: ScreenShot]

Please refer the attached image.
  We have the document_id and document_name in document_master table.
  Now, when we select the document name from the dropdown, we need to display the corresponding document_id (for the selected document name) from the document_master table.
  Can you please help us how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can always do an AJAX call to retrieve the related data from database. But, isn't it weird to retrieve the doc_ID based on doc_Name? usually its the other way around